# Formatting java.sql.Date to yyyyMMdd

Tags: java, date

I am using the below code

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Date d = new Date (2014,01,9);
System.out.println(d);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
final String text = df.format(d);
System.out.println(text);
```

I am getting below output.

```
3914-02-09
39140209
```

Does any one know why there is 3914?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc for the constructor you're using [`java.sql.Date(int,int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) reads (in part),

> *year* - the year minus 1900; must be 0 to 8099. (Note that 8099 is 9999 minus 1900.)

so you should use (assuming you mean *this* year)

```
Date d = new Date (2015-1900,01,9);
```

Comment: @Makoto Title of the question is *Formatting java.sql.Date to yyyyMMdd*

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch  why it is  "the year minus 1900; must be 0 to 8099. (Note that 8099 is 9999 minus 1900.)"? Any reason? can you please shed some light on this pleasE? Is it anyone's birthday?(might be the birthday of author of that class) lol :P

Comment: @MaheshVarma Because it was a reasonable epoch in the 1980s? I don't know, I didn't write the constructor (or the Javadoc).

Answer (score 2):

From Java Docs,

```
Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date).

Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents midnight, local time, at the beginning of the day specified by the year, month, and date arguments. 

Parameters:
year the year minus 1900.
month the month between 0-11.
date the day of the month between 1-31.
```

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        int year = 2014;
        int month = 01;
        int day = 9;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

        java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }
```

**output**

```
2014-01-09
```